# Bland-Altman plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is it possible to make a [Bland-Altman plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot) in Python? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Another name for this type of plot is the *Tukey mean-difference plot*.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just plot the dots using `plt.plot` and add the horizontal lines using `plt.axhline`? That plot seems easy enough to do.

Comment: Yes the plotting is easy. But I thought maybe there was a module in a lib which did the calculations too. For example I pass my 2 signals and it plots my plot. It's always average on the x axis and difference in the 2 signals on the y axis. The horizontal lines are the mean standard deviations (neg and pos)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I have understood the theory behind the plot correctly, this code should provide the basic plotting, whereas you can configure it to your own particular needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def bland_altman_plot(data1, data2, *args, **kwargs):
    data1     = np.asarray(data1)
    data2     = np.asarray(data2)
    mean      = np.mean([data1, data2], axis=0)
    diff      = data1 - data2                   # Difference between data1 and data2
    md        = np.mean(diff)                   # Mean of the difference
    sd        = np.std(diff, axis=0)            # Standard deviation of the difference

    plt.scatter(mean, diff, *args, **kwargs)
    plt.axhline(md,           color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md + 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md - 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
```

The corresponding elements in `data1` and `data2` are used to calculate the coordinates for the plotted points.

Then you can create a plot by running e.g.

```
from numpy.random import random

bland_altman_plot(random(10), random(10))
plt.title('Bland-Altman Plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: Bland-Altman Plot]

Comment: Shouldn't be `md + 1.96*sd` and `md - 1.96*sd` instead?

Comment: `plt.xlabel("Average of 2 measures")` and `plt.ylabel("Difference between 2 measures")` may be added to clarify x and y axes.

Comment: This will break if the data contains NaN.  Change `np.mean` to `np.nanmean` and `np.std` to `np.nanstd` to fix this.

Answer (score 28):

This is now implemented in statsmodels: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.agreement.mean_diff_plot.html

Here is their example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Seed the random number generator.
# This ensures that the results below are reproducible.
np.random.seed(9999)
m1 = np.random.random(20)
m2 = np.random.random(20)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (8,5))
sm.graphics.mean_diff_plot(m1, m2, ax = ax)

plt.show()
```

which produces this:

[image]

Comment: Should be the correct answer for up to date installations!

Answer (score 4):

I modified a bit the excellent code of @sodd to add a few more labels and text so that it would maybe be more publication ready

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pdb
from numpy.random import random

def bland_altman_plot(data1, data2, *args, **kwargs):
    data1     = np.asarray(data1)
    data2     = np.asarray(data2)
    mean      = np.mean([data1, data2], axis=0)
    diff      = data1 - data2                   # Difference between data1 and data2
    md        = np.mean(diff)                   # Mean of the difference
    sd        = np.std(diff, axis=0)            # Standard deviation of the difference
    CI_low    = md - 1.96*sd
    CI_high   = md + 1.96*sd

    plt.scatter(mean, diff, *args, **kwargs)
    plt.axhline(md,           color='black', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(md + 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md - 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    return md, sd, mean, CI_low, CI_high


md, sd, mean, CI_low, CI_high = bland_altman_plot(random(10), random(10))
plt.title(r"$\mathbf{Bland-Altman}$" + " " + r"$\mathbf{Plot}$")
plt.xlabel("Means")
plt.ylabel("Difference")
plt.ylim(md - 3.5*sd, md + 3.5*sd)

xOutPlot = np.min(mean) + (np.max(mean)-np.min(mean))*1.14

plt.text(xOutPlot, md - 1.96*sd, 
    r'-1.96SD:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % CI_low, 
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    )
plt.text(xOutPlot, md + 1.96*sd, 
    r'+1.96SD:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % CI_high, 
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    )
plt.text(xOutPlot, md, 
    r'Mean:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % md, 
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    )
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I took sodd's answer and made a plotly implementation. This seems like the best place to share it easily.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
def bland_altman_plot(data1, data2, data1_name='A', data2_name='B', subgroups=None, plotly_template='none', annotation_offset=0.05, plot_trendline=True, n_sd=1.96,*args, **kwargs):
    data1 = np.asarray( data1 )
    data2 = np.asarray( data2 )
    mean = np.mean( [data1, data2], axis=0 )
    diff = data1 - data2  # Difference between data1 and data2
    md = np.mean( diff )  # Mean of the difference
    sd = np.std( diff, axis=0 )  # Standard deviation of the difference


    fig = go.Figure()

    if plot_trendline:
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(mean, diff)
        trendline_x = np.linspace(mean.min(), mean.max(), 10)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=trendline_x, y=slope*trendline_x + intercept,
                                 name='Trendline',
                                 mode='lines',
                                 line=dict(
                                        width=4,
                                        dash='dot')))
    if subgroups is None:
        fig.add_trace( go.Scatter( x=mean, y=diff, mode='markers', **kwargs))
    else:
        for group_name in np.unique(subgroups):
            group_mask = np.where(np.array(subgroups) == group_name)
            fig.add_trace( go.Scatter(x=mean[group_mask], y=diff[group_mask], mode='markers', name=str(group_name), **kwargs))



    fig.add_shape(
        # Line Horizontal
        type="line",
        xref="paper",
        x0=0,
        y0=md,
        x1=1,
        y1=md,
        line=dict(
            # color="Black",
            width=6,
            dash="dashdot",
        ),
        name=f'Mean {round( md, 2 )}',
    )
    fig.add_shape(
        # borderless Rectangle
        type="rect",
        xref="paper",
        x0=0,
        y0=md - n_sd * sd,
        x1=1,
        y1=md + n_sd * sd,
        line=dict(
            color="SeaGreen",
            width=2,
        ),
        fillcolor="LightSkyBlue",
        opacity=0.4,
        name=f'±{n_sd} Standard Deviations'
    )

    # Edit the layout
    fig.update_layout( title=f'Bland-Altman Plot for {data1_name} and {data2_name}',
                       xaxis_title=f'Average of {data1_name} and {data2_name}',
                       yaxis_title=f'{data1_name} Minus {data2_name}',
                       template=plotly_template,
                       annotations=[dict(
                                        x=1,
                                        y=md,
                                        xref="paper",
                                        yref="y",
                                        text=f"Mean {round(md,2)}",
                                        showarrow=True,
                                        arrowhead=7,
                                        ax=50,
                                        ay=0
                                    ),
                                   dict(
                                       x=1,
                                       y=n_sd*sd + md + annotation_offset,
                                       xref="paper",
                                       yref="y",
                                       text=f"+{n_sd} SD",
                                       showarrow=False,
                                       arrowhead=0,
                                       ax=0,
                                       ay=-20
                                   ),
                                   dict(
                                       x=1,
                                       y=md - n_sd *sd + annotation_offset,
                                       xref="paper",
                                       yref="y",
                                       text=f"-{n_sd} SD",
                                       showarrow=False,
                                       arrowhead=0,
                                       ax=0,
                                       ay=20
                                   ),
                                   dict(
                                       x=1,
                                       y=md + n_sd * sd - annotation_offset,
                                       xref="paper",
                                       yref="y",
                                       text=f"{round(md + n_sd*sd, 2)}",
                                       showarrow=False,
                                       arrowhead=0,
                                       ax=0,
                                       ay=20
                                   ),
                                   dict(
                                       x=1,
                                       y=md - n_sd * sd - annotation_offset,
                                       xref="paper",
                                       yref="y",
                                       text=f"{round(md - n_sd*sd, 2)}",
                                       showarrow=False,
                                       arrowhead=0,
                                       ax=0,
                                       ay=20
                                   )
                               ])
    return fig
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm missing something, but this seems pretty easy:

```
from numpy.random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = random(25)
y = random(25)

plt.title("FooBar")
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.axhline(y=0.5,linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Here I just create some random data between 0 and 1 and I randomly put a horizontal line at y=0.5 -- but you could put as many as you want wherever you want.

Comment: It is not bland-altman plot. In bland-altman plot, the y axil shold be the **difference** between two groups of data.

Answer (score 0):

pyCompare has the Bland-Altman plot (see [demo from Jupyter](https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/jaketmp-pycompare-r23lfrql/notebooks/pyCompare-Demo.ipynb) )

```
import pyCompare
method1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
method2 = [1.03, 2.05, 2.79, 3.67, 5.00, 5.82, 7.16, 7.69, 8.53, 10.38, 11.11, 12.17, 13.47, 13.83, 15.15, 16.12, 16.94, 18.09, 19.13, 19.54]
pyCompare.blandAltman(method1, method2)
```

details on the pyCompare module [in PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyCompare/)

the end product looks like:[image]

Answer (score 0):

A clarification about this module:

When comparing a set of measurements with one from a reference method, a common mistake regarding the Bland-Altman plot is to use the average of the two measurments as x- values.

According to Bland&Altman, in case where a reference method exists, we should plot the reference values as x values instead of the average of the 2 measurements.

Sadly, this possibility is laking in the dedicated module (as in R).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also came to this post looking for examples of how to draw a Bland-Altman chart. In my case, I would like to add the method I have ended up using myself, where I take into account the case to be able to use a reference to draw the differences as @Gwénolé suggested, as well as to be able to draw with the variable 'hue' the values found (as in Seaborn).
I hope this will be of help to the community:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

def hue_rule(df1, df2, hue=None):
    if hue is None:
        return None 
    if hue not in df1.columns or hue not in df2.columns:
        raise ValueError(f"The 'hue' variable '{hue}' is not present in both DataFrames.")

    # Filter only the rows where the 'hue' values are identical in both DataFrames
    common_values = df1[df1[hue].eq(df2[hue])][hue].unique()

    # Create a dictionary that assigns each unique value in 'hue' a color
    color_dict = {val: sns.color_palette("colorblind")[i] for i, val in enumerate(common_values)}

    # Map 'hue' values to colors using the dictionary
    colors = df1[hue].map(color_dict)

    return colors


def bland_altman_plot(df1, df2, *args, x=None, axs=None, hue=None, reference=None, confidence_interval=1.96, **kwargs):
    if axs is None:
        axs = plt.axes()
    data1     = df1[x]
    data2     = df2[x]
    data1     = np.asarray(data1)
    data2     = np.asarray(data2)
    mean      = np.mean([data1, data2], axis=0)
    diff      = data1 - data2                   # Difference between data1 and data2
    md        = np.mean(diff)                   # Mean of the difference
    sd        = np.std(diff, axis=0)            # Standard deviation of the difference
    CI_low    = md - confidence_interval*sd
    CI_high   = md + confidence_interval*sd

    colors = hue_rule(df1, df2, hue=hue)

    if reference is None:
        axs.scatter(mean, diff,   c=colors, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        axs.scatter(reference, diff, c=colors, *args, **kwargs)

    axs.axhline(md,           color='black', linestyle='-')
    axs.axhline(md + confidence_interval*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    axs.axhline(md - confidence_interval*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')

    xOutPlot = np.min(mean) + (np.max(mean)-np.min(mean))*1.14

    axs.text(xOutPlot, md - confidence_interval*sd, r'-'+str(confidence_interval)+'SD:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % CI_low, ha = "center", va = "center")
    axs.text(xOutPlot, md + confidence_interval*sd, r'+'+str(confidence_interval)+'SD:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % CI_high, ha = "center", va = "center")
    axs.text(xOutPlot, md, r'Mean:' + "\n" + "%.2f" % md, ha = "center", va = "center")
    
    
    axs.set_ylim(md - 3.5*sd, md + 3.5*sd)
    return axs

data1 = {
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 101, size=20),  
    'B': np.random.choice(['x', 'y', 'z'], size=20)
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Crear DataFrame 2
data2 = {
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 101, size=20),
    'B': np.random.choice(['x', 'y', 'z'], size=20)
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
axs = bland_altman_plot(df1, df2, x='A', hue='B')

axs.set_ylabel("Difference")
    
axs.set_title('Difference df1 vs df2')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]